# @Observable vs @MainActor return Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context

Tags: ios, swift, observable, mainactor

I'm working with `DataScannerViewController` to give the user the ability to recognize text using the camera.

I created a template to manage camera permissions.

I uses `@Observable` macro and I need to use it on the main tread also using `@MainActor` macro

Now the problem is that the compiler gives me an error:

> Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous
> nonisolated context

at this line `@State private var scannerViewModel = ScannerViewModel()`

How can this problem be solved?

It seems that `@MainActor` conflicts with `@Observable`

This is the code

---

```
import Foundation
import VisionKit

enum ScannerStatus {
    case notDeterminated, denied, cameraNotAvailable, scannerNotAvailable, available
}

@MainActor
@Observable
final class ScannerViewModel {
    var accessStatus: ScannerStatus = .notDeterminated
    var scannerAvailable: Bool {
            DataScannerViewController.isSupported &&
            DataScannerViewController.isAvailable
        }
}


@main
struct FindTextFromImageApp: App {

@State private var scannerViewModel = ScannerViewModel() // Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous  nonisolated context

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        Start()
            .environment(scannerViewModel)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove MainActor from the class and apply it only where (if) it’s needed is one way to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actor isolate @Observable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746299/actor-isolate-observable-type)

Comment: @Timmy I wanted to avoid the use of `nonisolated init() {}`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson at this point I could just use the `@MainActor
    func requestAccess() async {var scannerAvailable: Bool {
                DataScannerViewController.isSupported &&
                DataScannerViewController.isAvailable
            } }`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `nonisolated init`?

Comment: @Sweeper This could introduce a potential data race: the initialisation of stored properties from within the non-isolated init function may not cause a hop to the MainActor executor. Later, the stored property will be read from the MainActor - which means a data race.

Comment: A possible solution could be to "implicitly" assume, that the initialiser will be called on the Main Thread. Given that, you can declare the init "non-isolated" and then use the [MainActor.assumeIsolated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/assumeisolated(_:file:line:)-swift.type.method) function. Please read the warnings in the docs! ;)